# interpreting ncol result in plyr package's each() function

Tags: r, plyr

I ran a query and got the below result:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mtcars, "cyl", each(nrow,ncol))
```

result is:

```
  cyl nrow ncol
1   4   11   11
2   6    7   11
3   8   14   11
```

Why all the values of "ncol" in the above result is 11?

what ncol in the each() means and results?

Comment: `dim(mtcars)#
[1] 32 11`  The number of rows changes for each 'cyl', but the ncol is the same, isn't it?  Or what do you expect as output?

Comment: I already did this.. and got 11 columns. but i was wondering to use of columns in each() with ddply() whereas we are using only one variable `"cyl"`

Answer (score 1):

Here, we are using one grouping variable i.e. 'cyl', but the `.data` is still 'mtcars' with 11 columns.  If we need to get only a single column, subset the data

```
plyr::ddply(mtcars['cyl'], "cyl", plyr::each(nrow,ncol))
#  cyl nrow ncol
#1   4   11    1
#2   6    7    1
#3   8   14    1
```